# why are images not showing in my rails app?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

i have made a simple website using a free template.  i am confused because the images on my version are not showing but the images on the demo version are working and both have exactly the same css files and html because i copy pasted. i will post them below. my confusion lies in the fact that i dont see any of the images reffered to in either the html or the css stylesheet.  the styling is there for the images but no link to the file location. 2 questions.

this is what the site should look like:

http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/bryantsmith/greenmountain/

this is what my site looks like:

https://cherry-cupcake-30790.herokuapp.com/

as you can see background, background to the navbar and main images are missing but other styling and css are implemented.

1. why are the images not showing on my version?
2. why are the images showing on the demo version 0hen there seems to be no reference to the actual file location of the image (only styling of the image)?

thanks.

html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>NightBeach | florida web design</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
        <div id="mainpic">
            <h1>Green<span class="off">Mountain</span></h1>
            <h2>A template by Bryant Smith</h2>
        </div>   

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Design</a></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h2>You may use this template in any manner you like. All I ask is that you leave the link back to my site at the bottom of the page. </h2>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <h3>Template Notes</h3>
            <p>The main image can be changed by either replacing the current image with another one of the same size (900x402), or using a new one of what ever dimensions you'd like.  If you choose the latter, you must open up style.css and change the dimensions of #mainpic, as well as the file name if that is different. If you would like to move the heading around in the above image, find &quot;#mainpic h1&quot; in style.css and modify it's &quot;left&quot; and &quot;top&quot; properties, this is also true for the h2 tag.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
<h3>More information</h3>
            <p>I decided to leave the content portion open for the templates users to do as they wish with a blank canvas. I don't like to restrict my users too much, and for this reason I leave the defining of any content related styles to you.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h3>Template Notes</h3>
            <p>The main image can be changed by either replacing the current image with another one of the same size (900x402), or using a new one of what ever dimensions you'd like.  If you choose the latter, you must open up style.css and change the dimensions of #mainpic, as well as the file name if that is different. If you would like to move the heading around in the above image, find &quot;#mainpic h1&quot; in style.css and modify it's &quot;left&quot; and &quot;top&quot; properties, this is also true for the h2 tag.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h3>More information</h3>
            <p>I decided to leave the content portion open for the templates users to do as they wish with a blank canvas. I don't like to restrict my users too much, and for this reason I leave the defining of any content related styles to you.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

            <div id="footer"><h3><a href="http://www.bryantsmith.com">florida web design</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
/* A Free Design by Bryant Smith (bryantsmith.com) */



body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #061C37;
    background: #EEEFE4;
    background-image:url(images/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
*
{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 text-align:left;}

#container
{
  display: block; 
  height:auto;
  position: relative; 
  width: 940px;
}

#mainpic h1
{
    position:absolute;
text-align:right;
color:#F8FDEE;
font-size:30px;
color:#FFF; 
left:60px;
top:20px;
}


#mainpic h2
{
position:absolute;
text-align:right;
color:#E1E7F7;  
left:60px;
top:50px;
}

#mainpic
{
background-image:url(images/main.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:900px;
height:354px;   
}



.off
{
color:#3A6028;

}




#menu
{
background-image:url(images/menu.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:940px;
height:69px;
float:left;
clear:both;
}

#content
{
width:880px;
height:auto;
background-color:#FFF;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}

#footer
{
width:inherit;
height:auto;
}

#footer h3 a,#footer h3 a:visited
{
display:inline;
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#7198E1;
}


#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:900px;
}

#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;   
    display: inline; 

}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 17px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#menu a:hover{
    color:#BEE399;
}

#content p
{

}


html, body {
text-align: center;
}
p {text-align: left;}




  [1]: http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/bryantsmith/greenmountain/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for problem 1, because your website's css is empty, nothing in. The css link is https://cherry-cupcake-30790.herokuapp.com/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css .

for problem 2, the image link refer is not in the html, but in the css file.

```
#mainpic {
  background-image: url(images/main.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 900px;
  height: 354px;
}
```

the image link is http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/bryantsmith/greenmountain/images/main.jpg

Comment: yes my bad on number 2. i see the reference to it now. however, what do you mean by my css is empty? could you please elaborate. as far as i see i have a css file in my rails app in the stylesheets folder and this should be included in the website no?

Comment: please try the website link again. i hadnt pushed to heroku before. its fixed now and you can see all the styling is there apart from the images.  https://cherry-cupcake-30790.herokuapp.com/

Comment: i mean according to chrome devtools, your website do have a application css file include, but it has no content, just empty. I guess you put a css file in stylesheets, but you didn't include it in the application.css.

Comment: yes, it's updating now. The new error is that the image 404. https://cherry-cupcake-30790.herokuapp.com/assets/images/main.jpg 404 (Not Found). You need to capture those images, and put it at `assets/images`, and change the url in css to `image-url('main.jpg')`. Or put the images directly into `public/images` directory.

Comment: changing the name seems to work.  why was it originally written (images/main.jpg) and not ('main.jpg')? and how can i know which of those way sof writing it is appropriate for the future?

Comment: The original site might not be rails.check the rails assets documents, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass